# Scala Left Join returns result of Full Join

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I tried to do Join two dataframes in spark shell.
One of the dataframe is having 15000 records and another is having 14000 rows.
I tried Left outer join and inner join of these dataframes, but result is having count of 29000 rows.
How is that happening?
The code which i tried is given below.

```
val joineddf = finaldf.as("df1").join(cosmos.as("df2"), $"df1.BatchKey" === $"df2.BatchKey", "left_outer").select(($"df1.*"),col("df2.BatchKey").as("B2"))
```

```
val joineddf = finaldf.as("df1").join(cosmos.as("df2"), $"df1.BatchKey" === $"df2.BatchKey", "inner").select(($"df1.*"),col("df2.BatchKey").as("B2"))
```

Both above methods are resulted in a dataframe where count is sum of both dataframes.

Even I tried the below method, but still getting same result.

```
finaldf.createOrReplaceTempView("df1")
cosmos.createOrReplaceTempView("df2")
val test = spark.sql("""SELECT df1.*, df2.* FROM  df1 LEFT OUTER JOIN  df2 ON trim(df1.BatchKey) == trim(df2.BatchKey)""")
```

If i try to add more condition for join then the no of count is again increasing.

How to get exact result for a left outer join?
here in the case max count should be 15000

Comment: do you have duplicate batch _id in both the dataframe?.

Comment: no. batch id is unique @Mahesh Gupta

Comment: can you share sample data of both the dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

Antony,

Can you try performing the join below :

```
val joineddf = finaldf.join(cosmos.select("BatchKey"), Seq("BatchKey"), "left_outer")
```

Here I'm not using any alias.